# Marcar checkbox a partir de resultado do bd

Tags: javascript

Tenho uma tabela que trás dados de cameras do bd e através dela eu seleciono pelo checkbox as cameras e gravo o id delas na mesma coluna dividindo por ','. queria saber como faço para quando ir editar trazer os dados das cameras e marcar as que foram registradas no banco.

código de como carrego a tabela câmeras

function carregar_cameras(){

```
    var url = "../api/cameras/return.php?condominio_id="+$("#condominio_id").val();
    $.post(url, function( data ) {
        var temp = '';

        temp = "<thead><tr><th onclick=\"selall2();\">Selecionar</th><th>ID</th><th>Descrição</th><th>Tipo</th></tr></thead><tbody>";

        $.each(data,function(index,value){

            temp+="<tr>"+
                                "<td><input type=\"checkbox\" id=\"user-"+value.id+"\"  name=\"user-"+value.id+"\" class=\"scheck2\"/></td>"+
                                "<td>"+value.id+"</td>"+
                                "<td>"+value.descricao+"</td>"+
                                "<td>"+value.tipo+"</td>"+
                        "</tr>";
        });

        temp+= "</tbody>";

        if (table2 != false){
            table2.destroy();
        }
     $('#tabelacameras').html(temp);
     setTimeout(function(){
            if ( $.fn.dataTable.isDataTable( '#tabelacameras' ) ) {
            table2 = $('#tabelacameras').DataTable();
            }else {
                table2 = $('#tabelacameras').DataTable( {
                    paging: false,
                } );
            }
     },800);

    },"json");

}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Acabei achando a resposta

e minha function de editar ficou assim:

```
function editpopup(id){
        $("#myModal").modal('show');
        carregar_cameras_condominio();
        $.each(global_ar,function(index,value){
            if (value.id == id){
                $("#id").val(value.id);
                $("#descricao").val(value.descricao);
                $("#cameras").val(value.cameras);
                var xcam = value.cameras.split(',');
                var xa = value.tipos.split(',');
                setTimeout(function(){

                    for (var i = 0; i < xcam.length; i++) {

                      $("#user-"+xcam[i]).prop("checked",true);
                    }

                },1000);
                for (var i = 0; i < xa.length; i++) {
                $("#user-"+xa[i]).prop("checked",true);
            }
        }       
        });
    }
```

Uso o setTimeout para dar tempo de carregar as lista de câmeras e só depois marcar os checkbox como true.